# cannot scroll iframe content on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, iframe

I am using a modal window on my page, which actually has a frameset page called within an iframe. The code to dynamically append the modal window is like;

```
$("#TB_window").append("<iframe frameborder='0' hspace='0' src='"+urlNoQuery[0]+"' id='TB_iframeContent' name='TB_iframeContent"+Math.round(Math.random()*1000)+"' onload='tb_showIframe()' style='width:"+(ajaxContentW + 29)+"px;height:"+(ajaxContentH + 17)+"px;' > </iframe>");
```

The generated HTML looks like;

```
<div id="TB_window" style="margin-left: -500px; width: 1001px; display: block;">
<iframe frameborder="0" style="width:1000px;height:581px;" onload="tb_showIframe()" name="TB_iframeContent805" id="TB_iframeContent" src="framesetPg.html" hspace="0"> </iframe></div>
</div>
```

Now while on IE, I can scroll through the main page as well as the inner frames, on Firefox, I cannot scroll completely through the main frameset page..

**Also to summarize this issue and this is something which should help identify where the problem lies;
If I hide the Windows Taskbar so that more vertical space is available for Firefox window, I can see the complete frameset page ...So something like viewport or based on display height. Reverse is also true i.e. if I drag the taskbar up, so that less space is available for FF, it only shows that much content and I cannot scroll the rest..**

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: are u using jquery ? if yes which plugin ?

Comment: Yes...I am using Thickbox plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this

```
$("body").css("overflow", "auto");
$("html").css("overflow", "auto");
```

to top of `tb_show` function in [thickbox.js](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/thickbox-code/thickbox.js) uncompressed here is exapmple
**This is How it's look**

```
function tb_show(caption, url, imageGroup) {//function called when the user clicks on a thickbox link

    try {
        if (typeof document.body.style.maxHeight
```

**change it to this**

```
function tb_show(caption, url, imageGroup) {//function called when the user clicks on a thickbox link
    $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
    $("html").css("overflow", "auto");
    try {
        if (typeof document.body.style.maxHeight
```

And leave the rest in peace **if not work post it to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) let me see it**

Comment: Thx a lot...I did try that..It did show the outer scrollbars in Firefox, but when we scroll down, it just moves the scrollbars down without actually scrolling through the main frameset page...Bcoz of proprieraty reasons, I am  really sorry that I can's share the entire code with you..

Comment: @hmthr man clould u just try another modal , thickbox is a long dead modal plugin try [simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) , [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) , etc and in between if you using any other js library , plugin ... make sure there is no conflicting issue with thickbox